# How to remove customtkinter after button is pressed again

Tags: python, customtkinter

I have been trying to develope a python app fpr weather and i have came across and issue that i cant find any info about. Wehn i press the button it give me temperature and at some point in the futre the weather and other things. So after i press the button it displays the temperature and if i press it again it displays the old and new temp. How should I go about fixing this?

```
import Weather
import customtkinter as ctk
import threading


def search_weather():

    city = weather_ser.get()

    temp = Weather.get_temp(city)
    weather = Weather.get_weather(city)

    dis_temp = ctk.CTkLabel(master=frame, text="", font=("Ariel", 16))
    dis_temp.configure(f'Temperature: {temp}')
    dis_temp.pack(padx=5, pady=5)


    weather_ser.delete(0, 'end')



mainwindow = ctk.CTk()
mainwindow.geometry("400x600")
mainwindow.title("Weather App")
mainwindow.iconbitmap('WeatherIco.ico')

frame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=mainwindow)
frame.pack()

label = ctk.CTkLabel(master=frame, text="Search for Cities", font=("Ariel", 24))
label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

weather_ser = ctk.CTkEntry(master=frame, placeholder_text="Search for a city")
weather_ser.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

search = ctk.CTkButton(master=frame, text="Search", command=search_weather)
search.pack(padx=8, pady=8)

mainwindow.mainloop()
```

-destroying the label but I might of done it wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is because every time you call `search_weather()` - new `Label` element appends to `frame`.

All your app elements are packed in frame, so inside `search_weater`, before appending new `dis_temp` Label to frame, you should remove all previous Labels. You can do it like that:

```
def search_weather():
    city = weather_ser.get()

    temp = Weather.get_temp(city)
    weather = Weather.get_weather(city)

    # Removing all labels inside frame
    for child in frame.winfo_children():
        if child.widgetName == "label":
            child.destroy()

    dis_temp = ctk.CTkLabel(master=frame, text="", font=("Ariel", 16))
    dis_temp.configure(f'Temperature: {temp}')
    dis_temp.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

    weather_ser.delete(0, 'end')
```

Comment: I have tried to implement the code but it doesnt seem to work. In the for loop when you search for "label" does this have to be another name or does this stay as "label"?

Comment: @LIlkahuna oh, yes, It probably has to be another name, I tested it at vanilla tkinter. You should check what `widgetName` property has `CTkFrame`. Try printing it (`print(child.widgetName)`) in for-loop before that `if-check`, and change `label` inside `if-check` to proper widgetName.

Comment: I have printed out multiple statements regarding the children of the frame object. I have been returned multiple objects and the second label is called CTk.Label2 or something like that but when i plug that into the if statement it still doesnt delete it. This is an example of what gets printed when use frame.winfo_children:
[<customtkinter.windows.widgets.ctk_label.CTkLabel object .!ctkframe.!ctklabel>
The child.widgetName method just prints "frame"